# Hide button after confirmation in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a button.It will show a Yes/No confirmation box when clicks on it.I want to hide the button when user clicks on 'Yes' button.My code is here

```
 <input type="button" name='hide_button' id='hide_button' value="Hide?"onClick="return confirm_hide();">
```

Javascript :

```
function confirm_hide(){
if(confirm('Do you wish to hide the button?'))
    return true;
else return false;
}
```

Comment: `confirm_hide != confirm_delete` and you can't hide a button just because you are returning false to `onclick`

Comment: corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `display` style property to `none`.

```js
function confirm_hide(ele) {
  if (confirm('Do you wish to hide the button?')) {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name='hide_button' id='hide_button' value="Hide?" onClick="return confirm_hide(this);">
```

Answer (score 1):

the following code help you add your button element id inplace

```
function confirm_delete(){
if(confirm('Do you wish to hide the button?')){
    var yesBtn = document.getElementById('yesBtn');
        yesBtn.style.display = 'none';
    return true;
}
else 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this function will help you

```
function confirm_hide() {
  if (confirm('Do you wish to hide the button?')) {
      $("#hide_button").hide();
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

Thank you...